# Trouble returning pointer from vector

Tags: c++

I am following a C++ game tutorial series from youtube. The following link is the one.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsvI8Sng6dk

So basically I am trying to implement a ECS system to my own game framework which uses raylib instead of SDL. The following is the code I followed from the video.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <array>

class Component;
class Entity;

using ComponentID = std::size_t;

inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID()
{
    static ComponentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() noexcept
{
    static ComponentID typeID = getComponentTypeID();
    return typeID;
}

constexpr std::size_t maxComponents = 32;

using ComponentBitSet = std::bitset<maxComponents>;
using ComponentArray = std::array<Component*, maxComponents>;

class Component
{
public:
    Entity* entity;

virtual void Init() {}
virtual void Update() {}
virtual void Draw() {}

virtual ~Component() {}
};


class Entity
{
public:
    void Update() 
{
    for (auto& c : components) c->Update();
}

void Draw() 
{
    for (auto& c : components) c->Draw();
}
bool IsActive() const { return active; }
void Destroy() { active = false; }

template<typename T> bool HasComponent() const
{
    return ComponentBitSet[getComponentTypeID<T>()];
}

template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
T& AddComponent(TArgs&&... mArgs)
{
    T* c(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...));
    c->entity = this;
    std::unique_ptr<Component> uPtr{ c };
    components.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr));

    componentArray[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = c;
    componentBitSet[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = true;

    c->Init();
    return *c;
}

template <typename T> T& GetComponent() const
{
    auto ptr(componentArray[getComponentTypeID<T>()]);
    return *static_cast<T*>(ptr);
}

private:
    bool active = true;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

    ComponentArray componentArray;
    ComponentBitSet componentBitSet;
};

class Manager
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> entities;
public:
void Update()
{
    for (auto& e : entities) e->Update();
}

void Draw()
{
    for (auto& e : entities) e->Draw();
}

void Refresh()
{
    entities.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(entities), std::end(entities), [](const std::unique_ptr<Entity>& mEntity)
        {
            return !mEntity->IsActive();
        }),
        std::end(entities));
}

Entity& AddEntity()
{
    Entity* e = new Entity();
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> uPtr{ e };
    entities.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr));     
    return *e;
}

//Entity& AddEntity(std::unique_ptr<Entity>& ptr)
//{
//  ptr = std::make_unique<Entity>();
//  entities.emplace_back(std::move(ptr));
//  count++;
//  return *entities[count - 1];
//}
};
```

The problem I am having is that I can only write below in global to AddEntity to the entities list like following.

```
auto& player(manager.AddEntity());
```

However, I want to do something like the following:
    // SceneGame.h
    Entity player;

```
// SceneGame.cpp
manager.AddEntity(player);
```

The add entity process works fine but if I try to AddComponent to player it just showed error in debugging. It seems like I couldn't get the player pointer. The following is the version of my own AddEntity code:

```
Entity& AddEntity(std::unique_ptr<Entity>& ptr)
{
    ptr = std::make_unique<Entity>();
    entities.emplace_back(std::move(ptr));
    return ptr;     
}
```

Honestly speaking I think it's just lack of understanding how pointers. Although I do use shared_ptr in this project.
Could someone please help me out here? Thank you!

Comment: `ptr = std::make_unique<Entity>();` This makes no sense. You take a parameter, then immediately destroy the object it's holding and replace it with a default-constructed entity; then insert that. The data passed in by the caller is lost.

Comment: This is what happens when attempting to learn C++ from a Youtube video.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think if it was std::shared_ptr it would be okay right?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be. Why should `AddEntity` create a new instance of `Entity` object at all, when it already has one passed in as a parameter?

Comment: Guys, thank you for reply. After reviewing again, I think i have to take some time to understand how pointers really work. I guess I messed up the logic in my function.

Comment: @nicklowkc You may only have to change a couple things around, maybe initializing the player Entity outside of that AddEntity, then just adding it to the entities in that function. You're close.